# image copy paste in ckeditor through firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ckeditor

my problem is that with just copy paste i can copy image in ckeditor in firefox ,after copying this image it doesn,t get displayed in other browser how can i remove pasting of image in firefox[image]

Image urlis also looks  diffrent

Comment: will u please tell me how to enable copy/paste image from drive to CKEditor in asp.net ?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and IE8 *can* actually display it, if the file is smaller than 32 KB. IE7 can not display it, IE9 has no trouble.

If you want to use this functionality, you'd have to add some code server side that receives the HTML you provided, and before you submit it to the database extract the base64 encoded Data URI's and save them as 'regular' attachments in your database. You'd replace the data URIs with 'regular' uris that point to the image assets on your storage location.

We do something similar for the OTRS project: http://blog.otrs.org/2012/02/06/pasting-images-using-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured a file uploader in CKEditor, you can use this plugin to convert the pasted images into real files and upload them:

http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/ImagePaste-plugin-for-Firefox